# Ansible continue playbook after connection lost

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook like below,

```
    - name: Executing shell script
      shell: |
        cd "{{ mntout.stdout }}"
        sh config_script -f
      register: installo
      ignore_errors: yes

    - name: Formatting output
      shell: echo "{{ installo.stdout }}" | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,3}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[mGK]//g"
      register: trout
      delegate_to: localhost
      

    - name: Show output
      debug:
        msg: "{{ trout.stdout | replace('\r','\n')|replace('\n','\n') | replace('\b','') }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

So, Once the config script completes it will reboot the target(And I dont want to wait for target to come up).

But, I want the playbook to continue after connection lost and execute remaining tasks on localhost as I need to print the output of the script. Any suggestions?

Need to continue even after below error

```
fatal: [147.234.158.192]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ", "unreachable": true}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where in your playbook the target machine reboots. The best you can do is to let Ansible reboot the target machine with the [reboot module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/reboot_module.html). Especially since you're expecting the machine to reboot.

```yaml
- name: Reboot a slow machine that might have lots of updates to apply
  reboot:
    reboot_timeout: 3600
```

Comment: Actually, The config script will issue reboot command. In My playbook target machine reboots at "Executing shell script" task. Even I tried using ```ignore_unreachable: yes``` in the task "Executing shell script". But am not able collect registered output which is "installo.stdout"

Comment: Edit the 'config_script' so that the machine does not reboot.

Comment: That is the problem. The config script will be available from ISO file..we will be mounting the ISO file and run the script. We cannot do any changes to the config script.